# Can I use both parametric and non-parametric tests?

Tags: anova, normal-distribution, kruskal-wallis-test

I have 3 variables, A1, A2 and A3

```
A1 is temperature
A2 is month
A3 is location
```

A2 has 2 months - March and May.
A3 has 2 cities - Chennai and Dubai.

My data is non-normally distributed and I am trying to compare the 3 groups with the Kruskall-Wallis test to see there is a difference between A2 and A3

> kruskal.test(my_data=data, A2~A3)

```
Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test
data:  A2 by A3
Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 0, df = 1, p-value = 1
```

is a p-value of 1 correct and can I do a ANOVA (Parametric test) to make sure that there is no difference between A2 and A3, even though the data is non-normally distributed?

Many Thanks, Ishack

Comment: "a difference between A2 and A3". a difference between month and location?

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: That doesn't make sense, month and location are not on the same scale (and neither sounds like a random variable). Your code also seems to have errors. What is the question you're trying to answer from these data? what is the working hypothesis?